# How to use RDD collect method to process each row of RDD in array format?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
//making an RDD 
val logData = sc.textFile(sampleData).cache()

//making logDataArray[String] 
 var logDataArray = logData.collect;
```

But its throwing me error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:717)
    at com.Travel$.com$Travel$$isConnected$1(Travel.scala:58)
```

Before using `logData.collect` I have check the size of logData as `println(logData.count)`. It give 1168 record size.

Comment: Your code looks correct. What version of Spark is this?

Comment: I am using 1.0.1 version of Spark

Comment: Can there be any issue with the spark version?

Comment: A million bugs have been fixed since 1.0.1. You should upgrade. But I'm not saying this is a Spark bug, I just wanted to see the line of code that has the `NullPointerException`. Here it is: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.0.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L717 It looks like `sc` is `null`. Are you sure you are running the exact code you quoted?

Comment: Could you add the code for `Travel.scala`?

Comment: Yes @DanielDarabos I have executed so many steps successfully. I also use `logData.foreach(println)` to print (working). But when I am using it in  another function its throwing me `NullPointerException` . The other function is the sub-function of parent one (i.e main method).

Comment: Actually when I checking the count in sub function as like in parent func. Its throwing me `NullPointerException` .  Am I missing some important concept of scala???

Comment: I can't imagine what may be going on there. One option is to not use "sub-functions" and just put everything in `main` :). Does `collect` work that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing this line ( var logDataArray = logData.collect )in some function, it is possible sc is not in scope and is getting null. Moreover everytime function is invoked, you will execute collect method.

Try adding line outside your function ie. directly in main method.
it is working for me.